# Centering div that is wider than its parent without setting negative left margin

Tags: css

I have a div inside a div.

The div inside is wider than its parent so the normal procedure

```
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
```

produces an inner div where the left edge of the child aligns with the left edge of the parent.

When people answers this question, they uses to go for the negative left margin approach. Is there a cleaner solution?

Comment: what do you mean by cleaner solution .. :D .. ?

Comment: That a negative margin is conceptually a non existing thing in the real world. However, most of the badness to this solutions comes from the required calculation that I need to do every time I change a measure.

Comment: But i don't think we can achieve this without using negative margin.. and to avoid different classes for different calculations we can use jquery.

Comment: Using negative values for margin is a valid approach. and there is no need of doing calculations every time when you change something if you use `percentages`. Check out this [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/k8E3Q/). (works if you know the widths of the containers)

Comment: When you mention knowing widths of containers, I have to add extra badness points to negative margins.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about using `position: absolute;` with `left:0;right:0;` and `margin: auto;`

Also, you'll need to place `position: relative;` on a parent element which has greater width than the outer element. (In the fiddle below it's relative to the body by default)

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/msVVD/2/)**

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

### css

```
.outer
{
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    background: beige;
    margin: 0 auto;

}
.inner
{
    width: 600px;
    height: 200px;
    background: pink;
    position: absolute;
    left:0;right:0;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: it is based on the solution mentioned here: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2013/08/09/absolute-horizontal-vertical-centering-css/

Comment: This could be the best answer. but no answer is going to be cleaner than a negative margin.

Comment: If I set position: relative on .outer, the child will be left align with it, why?

Comment: This one is good. Just need to give positioning to any ancestor element which has more width than the `inner` element which has been considered here. No need of positioning if the only ancestor element is `body` though.

Comment: @AndersLindén if you set position: relative on .outer, then it will do just that - ie positioning on .inner will start from the point where .outer starts (aligning .inner to the lhs of outer) So like I said in the answer -  you'll need to place position: relative; on a parent element which has greater width - which **relative to it** you want to center .inner

Comment: does not work unless you force the outer element to be centered itself, and also, this is a major fake solution since your outer element isn't relatively positioned, which must be set 99% of the cases...so I don't see any way to use this, at all

Answer (score 20):

You can use flexbox:

```css
.outer {
  display: flex; /* Magic begins */
  justify-content: center; /* Center contents */
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background: beige;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.inner {
  flex-shrink: 0; /* Don't shrink it even if it's too wide */
  width: 600px;
  height: 200px;
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This answer is really nice for a responsive layout with fluid measures.

Comment: In 2017+, this seems to be the best approach to me.

Comment: @Oriol I like this solution but unfortunately it doesn't work in IE. Is there a fix for IE?

Answer (score 18):

I worked out an easy way for absolute elements using a transform.

```
left: 50%;
transform: translateX(-50%);
```

Will center it if wider than parent.

Comment: Best answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If the inner is an image I prefer this one 
 `background: url("../img/pic.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;`

Answer (score 0):

See this website: http://www.greywyvern.com/?post=323

Works even if the page is narrower than the child div.

```css
div#context {
  border:1px solid blue;
  width:400px;
  margin:0px auto;
}
div#context div {
  position:relative;
  right:50%;
  text-align:center;
}
div#context div p {
  border:1px solid green;
  width:450px;
  height:50px;
  display:inline-block;
  margin-right:-100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="context">
  Page centering context
  <div>
<p>
  This is the child element<br />
  which should be centered
</p>
  </div>
</div>
```