# CSS text-align by parent smaller than child

Tags: css, text-align

I want the child to align centraly to its parent. The parent is smaller and that's what's causing the problem. https://jsfiddle.net/mkvaL7uy

The only solution I see here is to give the parent a fixed width - make it really wide + `height:0px`, create another element to replace the invisible parent, whereafter the child can align properly. https://jsfiddle.net/mkvaL7uy/1

Is there some other **non width-dependant** way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

There's an answer to achieve this in here: [Centering div that is wider than its parent without setting negative left margin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18309698/centering-div-that-is-wider-than-its-parent-without-setting-negative-left-margin)

The answer also points to this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/msVVD/2/.

Alternatively, you could use relative position between the two elements without setting rules for width. The one caveat is that `inner` will always be dependent upon `outer`'s width and `inner` will never be narrower than `outer`:

```css
.outer {
    background: beige;
    display: inline;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 100px;
}

.inner {
    background: pink;
    position: absolute;
    left: -50%;
    right: -50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  This text is short.
  <div class="inner">This text is not much longer than the one above.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: ok - will test it - as in my case, both widths varie

Comment: strangely, doesn't work - - the given fiddle does not align if sizes are not set (having the elements expandable by their content)

Comment: @Krupp, I edited the answer to show one way to do it without setting widths.

Comment: Good indeed, thanks, but - - this way, the width of the child is always 200% of the parent's. In my fiddle, the two can come in any size. Thanks again